# how to use cross debugger x86_64-w64-mingw32-gdb in linux to debug .exe

Tags: linux, gdb, mingw, exe

I typed " x86_64-w64-mingw32-gdb main.exe " to enter the cross debugging context.
Then I set some breakpoints.
After typing "r", it says "Don't know how to run. Try 'help target'."
Did I use the x86_64-w64-mingw32 in a wrong way? What the right commands should be?

Comment: The simplest approach  on Linux is to develop and debug your program for Linux, and once it is somehow running, work on porting it to some other operating system. So use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on Linux, and once your program is working on Linux, start porting it to Windows. Installing [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) on your laptop (after backing up important data) is probably the simplest approach. And your question needs some [mre]

Comment: If you code for Windows, consider using straight compilers on it. Perhaps [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B). Take inspiration from the source code *existing* open source software (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) ...). For Linux, see https://linuxfromscratch.org/ and notice that **cross-compilation is difficult.** When possible and allowed, avoid it

Comment: the problem described above is in WSL2 environment

Comment: But as far as this gdb is concerned, it's running on Linux, not in WSL2, so it doesn't know that it's actually possible to start the executable. Why do you not debug with a native gdb?

Comment: I think you need to run a Windows `gdbserver.exe` that will run and control your  `main.exe`, then start `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gdb` in WSL2 and use the command `target remote ipaddress:port` to connect to the gdbserver.